# I'm having problem in displaying mysql row to Datagridview

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

Hi im doing this for my class and i'm having trouble in displaying a selected row from my database to my datagridview. The Selected row displays at the datagridview but when i add the text or id it's called from, the text or id shows up twice, one at the upper left corner of the grid and one at the second column second row
Thiss my code so far

```
Private Function Row() As Object()
    Dim search As String = "select * from product where Product_ID='" + TextBox1.Text + "'"

    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(search, connection)
    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)

    adapter.Fill(table)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = table

End Function
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    table.Rows.Add(Row, TextBox1.Text)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = table

End Sub
```

i've tried datarow but it didnt work, i dont know if i jus used it wrongly or something... PLz help and thank you

Comment: Does table `product` has a primay key (Product_ID)? Also you should [parametrize your queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html)

Comment: Also I would 1. not set the DataSource again in the Click handler
2. Use a `BindingSource` and bind the table to it´s `DataSource` and then bind the BindingSource to the DataGridView´s DataSource

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several problems. Your function doesn't return anything. If a method (a Sub or Function) doesn't return a value, in your case an object array, then it should be a Sub with no datatype. No overload of `Rows.Add()` takes a DataRow and a string as parameters. You are assigning the `DataSource` twice.

Several database objects from ADO.net have `Dispose` methods. It is important that they are disposed because they use unmanaged code and they release resources in their `Dispose` method. `Using...End Using` blocks take care of this for us.

You can check if a certain object has a `Dispose` method with intellisense. The `Stream` objects (used in file reading and writing) also have `Dispose` methods.

Connections are precious objects and need to be closed and disposed as soon as possible. Therefore, they need to be local to the method where they are used so they can be enclosed in `Using` blocks. `End Using` closes and disposes included objects. The demo code below includes both the command and the connection in the Using block. Note the comma at the end of the first line of the Using.

**ALWAYS** use paramaters to avoid Sql injection.

Name your subs, functions and variables so they are self-documenting. Row doesn't tell us much.

```
Private Sub DisplayProductInfo()
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Using cn As New MySqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand("select * from product where Product_ID = @ProductID;", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", TextBox1.Text)
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you sirs, im fairly new to this, Thank you i will try to fix it